# Any alternative to print bulk message using unicode escape sequence \u00AD

Tags: java, swing

i have to print bulk message on display using \u format in java . i have to print bulk
messages on display in gujarati in java.i used tableHeader[0] = "ફોર્મ નંબર";it show correctly
in text editor but when compile it it dont apear properly in display

Comment: Java uses Unicode8 charset

Comment: Could you post some (minimalized) code, showing the problem? @VishalD: First of all, the character set is called Unicode (not Unicode8). Second, in Java a char (and thus also strings) are represented by the UTF-16 encoding (not UTF-8, that you potentially meant).

Comment: I'd say you have not specified the source encoding correctly. Check that the compiler is reading it in the same encoding as your editor uses.